# Allow the file input to be optional with bluimp plugin

Tags: jquery, angularjs, file-upload, blueimp

This question is partially addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15119386/optional-file-upload-with-blueimp-jquery-file-upload-plugin).

Only I am using the Angular version of the plugin, and I would like to allow my user to use the form that
the bluimp plugin is applied on even without a file.

I tried setting 'disableValidation' option to true, but it didn't help.

I thought to define a $scope variable once the 'fileuploadchange' event triggers at least one, and if this variable remain undefined, use another submit handler on the click or submit event.
But there must be a cleaner way than that.

A plunk to emphasize to problem:
http://plnkr.co/edit/J1JDYO?p=preview

Comment: Can you post a fiddle ? or a snippet of the your code to understand the problem better ?

Comment: Posted the plunker as you requested!

Answer (score 1):

Oleg, try to change button type to "submit"

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start" data-ng-click="submit()">
<span>Submit text field without file</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Will try and keep you posted